A chart element with the name 'Current Streak' could not be found in the 'SeriesCollection
I am running this function when the form loads. The error is recurring, but I'm not sure how to fix it.
private void addChartValues()
{
    ...
    string username;
    int currentStreak;
    int HighestStreak;
    int NumOfDaysAttempted;
    int FlashcardsCreatedNum;
    int OverdueCardNum;

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        username = reader.GetString(0);
        currentStreak = reader.GetInt32(1);
        HighestStreak = reader.GetInt32(2);
        NumOfDaysAttempted = reader.GetInt32(3);
        FlashcardsCreatedNum = reader.GetInt32(4);
        OverdueCardNum = reader.GetInt32(5);
        CurrentStreakChart.Series["Current Streak"].Points.AddXY(username, currentStreak);
        HighestStreakChart.Series["Highest Streak"].Points.AddXY(username, HighestStreak);
        NumAttemptedChart.Series["Number of Days Attempted"].Points.AddXY(username, NumOfDaysAttempted);
        CardsCreatedChart.Series["Number of Cards Created"].Points.AddXY(username, FlashcardsCreatedNum);
        OverdueCardsChart.Series["Number of Overdue Cards"].Points.AddXY(username, OverdueCardNum);
    }

    reader.Close();

    conn.Close();
}

I saw another answer about using var series = CurrentStreakChart.Series.Add("Current Streak"); but I'm not sure how to implement that here in my code. I'm unfamiliar with using charts, so I would really appreciate the help.
EDIT: I've implemented the series.add, but the charts are only showing the first pair of values in the database. I know that the sql statement is correct, there is some problem with the addxy.
CurrentStreakChart.Series.Add("Current Streak");
HighestStreakChart.Series.Add("Highest Streak");
NumAttemptedChart.Series.Add("Number of Days Attempted");
CardsCreatedChart.Series.Add("Number of Cards Created");
OverdueCardsChart.Series.Add("Number of Overdue Cards");


Clearly somewhere in your code you create the object CurrentStreakChart, and that's where you should add the named series.

I did do that but the addxy doesn't seem to be adding each pair of values from the while loop, only the first pairs to each chart.

Can you show what you've done by editing the post?

I have made the changes.

Put a breakpoint in the while loop. Does it go through the loop more than once? Can you see the contents of Points does not change the second time through?

The loop is definitely iterating more than once, it just doesn't seem to be inserting them. I did have to install the data visualization package because it isn't in my current version.

How do you know? Did you put a break point in and step through the code? Did you inspect the contents of Points?

I couldn't find a way inspect the contents of points using breakpoints, but I was able to inspect the variables, which are getting the correct data.
